# Hits Processed Per Month?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

If you refer to http://www.google.com/intl/en_uk/analytics/premium/features.html, you will notice that Standard allows for 10 million hits processed per month and Premium allows for 1 billion.

I have a website on an account, with multiple "folders" for different sub-domains, and also different "Views" or dashboards for some of these sub-domains.

The website I am on recently lost tracking for conversion rates, and everything has plummeted to near 0%, which is an incorrect statistic. I am curious as to how I can figure up if this account is reaching the 10 million limit on the standard version. Or at least how to figure actual hits processed a day, week, or month?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how Google enforces hit limits in 2015. However in 2013 a Google representative sent one of our bigger clients a document (answering a question about data limits) that contained the following paragraph:

> How do data limits impact sampling? Google Analytics does not sample
>   your clients data at the point of collection or processing, regardless
>   of how far they exceed our stated limits. So no hits are discarded.
>   The only way to sample data at the point of collection is for clients
>   to use_setSampleRate in their tracking code.
>
> [...]
>
> [...] we reserve the right to shutdown their account [sc. if limits are exceeded], but it won't
>   happen before we have attempted to contact the account Admins multiple times 
>   and we have exhausted all other options.

Unless Google has changed it's policy in the last 1,5 years I would say not, unprocessed hits are not your problem; it seems Google would have contacted you with an request to limit your hits or upgrade to Analytics Premium before problems occurr.

Plus, since you mentioned that you have several views - views do not count towards your quota (they display the same data in different ways). However properties (I think that is what you mean by "folders") do.

**Updated 2017**: It seems that Google intends to enforce limits more strictly. One of my clients now has the following warning in his GA interface:

[image]

> Your data volume (XXX hits) exceeds the limit of 10M hit per month as
>   outlined in our terms of service. **If you continue to exceed the limit
>   you will lose access to future data**.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database table, like this:

```
visits(
    id bigint primary key auto_increment,
    ip text,
    visit_date timestamp default current_timestamp
)
```

Upon each page visit, you can insert a record into the table. Later you can view statistics. For instance, visit count in a given day would look like:

```
select id, ip, visit_date
from visits
where visit_date >= '2015-07-21 00:00:00' and visit_date < '2015-07-22 00:00:00'
```